# Normalizer as a functor/monad

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, monads

I'll motivate my question with a neat observation: let $G$ be a group, and let $\mathcal{P}(G)$ denote the power set of $G$, regarded as a category in the usual way (i.e., as a poset converted into a categry). If $S\subseteq T$ are subsets of $G$, then the centralizers of $S$ and $T$ satisfy $C_G(T)\subseteq C_G(S)$. As it turns out, the centralizer determines a functor:
$$
C_G:\mathcal{P}(G)^{\mathrm{op}}\to\mathcal{P}(G),\quad C_G:S\mapsto C_G(S).
$$
One can show that $C_G$ is a right adjoint to its own opposite $C_G^{\mathrm{op}}:\mathcal{P}(G)\to\mathcal{P}(G)^{\mathrm{op}}$. We therefore have a "double centralizer monad" $T = C_G^2 = C_G\circ C_G^{\mathrm{op}}$ induced from this adjunction (the algebras are the "[self-bicommutant](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Centralizer_and_normalizer#Groups)" subgroups of $G$).

With this in mind, my question is:

> Q. Can the normalizer be viewed in a similar way?

Modifications to the category in question would likely be needed, since normalizers don't preserve (or reverse) inclusions...

Comment: The centralizer establishes a Galois connection between subsets (or subgroups) of $G$ and themselves. The adjunction really comes from that fact, which holds whenever you have a Galois connection between two posets.  This does not hold for the normalizer in any way that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Arturo described, this property of the centralizer comes from the Galois connection. So I think it would be unlikely to find a similar setting for the normalizer.

Despite this, I'll give a different categorical description of the normalizer so that this question is resolved.

Let $\mathcal{P}(G)$ be as above, and let $G$ act on it via conjugation. Then, we may consider the *action groupoid* $\mathcal{P}(G)//G$: this has subsets of $G$ as the objects, and morphisms from $S$ to $T$ given by elements $g\in G$ such that $g\cdot S = gSg^{-1} = T$.

Then, the automorphism group $\mathrm{Aut}_{\mathcal{P}(G)//G}(S)$ of an object $S$ in this category is the stabilizer of $S$ under this action, which is precisely $N_G(S)$.